# Strange host issue

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I spent several hours trying to figure this stuff out but with no luck.
I googled for this, and also searched by keywords right on stackoverflow.

So that, I'm asking question here.
As a panel, there's DirectAdmin.

When I enter DirectAdmin and create MySQL 
database it tells "Database has been created successfully".

And also tells : "use this data for your scripts"

```
Host     : localhost (yes, localhost! )
user     : db_user
password : db_password
databse  : db_name
```

Okay. It works WHEN I enter this data to phpMyAdmin
both - user and password. I can use SQL to manipulate data via phpMyAdmin.
It's just fine.

BUT

When I enter this data to some script

```
<?php

$host     = 'localhost';
$password     = 'db_password';
$db           = 'db_name';
$user     = 'db_user';

// I'm aware of PDO and I use this one but PDO isn't installed on my hosting provider
// This is just test to see if connection can be established

if ( ! mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) ){

    die( mysql_error() );
}
```

So it tells, that "Access denied for db_user@localhost Using password (YES)"!
What's the problem?! I entered correct data!

Then I tried to use adress of my site instead of 'localhost'.
Then `mysql_error()` tells something like this : "Connection from mysite.com is not allowed for this host".

Again - from phpMyAdmin I can see that: user - `db_user@localhost` (so that both username and host aren't wrong)

The question is: Why does it allow to connect from phpMyAdmin and does not from custom scripts?

**UPDATE 1**.
I have tried to change the `port` (as @Bondye suggested ) and `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` as well. But get the same error - `Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Here's MySQL section from PHP.INI

```
Active Persistent Links  0  
Active Links  0  
Client API version  5.1.53  
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE  external  
MYSQL_SOCKET  /tmp/mysql.sock  
MYSQL_INCLUDE  -I/usr/local/include/mysql  
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/local/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  

Param:              Local Value: Master Value: 

mysql.allow_persistent  Off      Off 
mysql.connect_timeout   60       60 
mysql.default_host      no value no value 
mysql.default_password  no value no value 
mysql.default_port      no value no value 
mysql.default_socket    no value no value 
mysql.default_user      no value no value 
mysql.max_links         5        5 
mysql.max_persistent    0        0 
mysql.trace_mode        Off      Off 



System : FreeBSD
```

I'm aware of both PDO and MySQLi but I can't use them. I must use old `mysql_*` functions for current script I'm working on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your mysql database and your webserver you are trying to connect from on the same machine?

Comment: the problem is that: YES they are on the same machine !

Comment: Do you have the option in your admin area to add a wildcard host `%` to allow connections from any host? Bit drastic but will get you up and running, alternatively you can find out your servers ip address and add that to the list of allowed connections

Comment: A rare case, but I've encontered it - 'localhost' might not resolve to 127.0.0.1 - try using that as a hostname.

Comment: @Narf just tried this. Didn't work

Comment: In the admin module ad a user db_user@127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: You can try to run `phpinfo();` and CRTL + F (search) for `mysql.default_port` If this is set to 3306 you are ok. Else you need to specify this number in you connection. Sometimes it is port 3307 `$link = mysql_connect('example.com:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');`

Comment: When you say "I *must* use the old `mysql` functions", is that because you're working on an existing codebase that already uses them? That's probably the only good reason for using them, and even then, converting to `mysqli` is really not a difficult task (actually very easy in most cases), and will improve your site security. It's also worth pointing out that the PHP devs have (as of this week) voted to officially deprecate the `mysql` functions in the forthcoming version PHP 5.5, meaning that it's no longer a hypothetical problem for the future - it's happening now.

Comment: @SDC I realize that and I'm aware of that. There's an old script that uses old mysql_* functions and I don't need to replace them. Nobody asked me to do that. Also I have mentioned I have not PDO support according to `phpinfo()`

Comment: @metal_fan - fair enough. as long as you're aware.  :)

Comment: Does your password contain special characters? I believe PHP's mysql connector defaults to LATIN-1, not UTF-8.

Comment: @wkoot No it does not. And It should not. My password itself is, like, `db_password_12345_test_dumb`, so that it's not UTF-8 string, but LATIN-1

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

> Note:
>
> Whenever you specify "localhost" or "localhost:port" as server, the
>   MySQL client library will override this and try to connect to a local
>   socket (named pipe on Windows). If you want to use TCP/IP, use
>   "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost". If the MySQL client library tries
>   to connect to the wrong local socket, you should set the correct path
>   as in your PHP configuration and leave the server field blank.

You might considor using mysqli instead (ends with i for improved)

```
Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

    mysqli_connect()
    PDO::__construct()
```